# Prove if $I$ is an ideal of $R$ ring, then $(I \cup \{x\})/(x) \cong I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-isomorphism

I am trying to prove the statement above where $(x)$ is the principal ideal generated by the polynom $x$ in $R[x]$, and similarly with $(I \cup \{x\})$. Additionally, I have to prove that $R[x]/(I \cup \{x\}) \cong R/I$ with the help of this statement. For this part, I know that $R[x]/(x) \cong R$ and I should use the 3rd (or maybe 2nd, I don't know which one it is in English) isomorphism theorem, but I'm clueless with the initial statement. I appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: Is $x$ the variable or an element in $R$?

Comment: Yes, an element, but the exercise didn't clarify it, I will edit the question.

Comment: This is untrue if, say, I is the principal ideal of x.

Comment: I asked becuase if $x \in I$ then $$(I \cup \{x\})/(x)= I/(x) $$ which is in many situations not isomorphic to $I$.

Comment: Yes, that's what bugged me as well, so I consulted with my prof, and he said that $(x)$  is the principal ideal generated by the polynom $x$ in $R[x]$. So $x$ is not an element, but a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $(I \cup \{x\})$ is a set of polynomials over $R$, so define a function $\varphi$ from $(I \cup \{x\})$ to $I$ which simply selects the constant term of this polynomial.

This is a homomorphism (this is easy to prove), surjective and its kernel is $(x)$, which proves your proposition through the first isomorphism theorem (sometimes called the homomorphism theorem)

Comment: I used something similar: if $f$ is an element in $(I \cup \{x\})$, then $ f \mapsto f(0)$ which basically has the same result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the first isomorphism theorem for the natural map $R[x]\to R/I$ sending $x\mapsto 0$.